# How do I make a lettered ordered list in HTML using CSS Style (not using type)

Tags: html, css

The question states this:

Do not use the type attribute to change the appearance of something. I know I have mentioned that in some circumstnaces it is okay. However, for this assignment - and for the course in general - remember that whenever you are changing the appearance of something (e.g. a font, color, bullet type, etc) you should always use CSS.

CREATE AN ORDERED LIST OF 3 PEOPLE, your list should use upper case letters, i.e. A, B, C, D instead of numbers.

Have to use CSS and can't use the type="A" attribute tag.

Tried list-style but not sure what to use.

Comment: You need to provide code.

Answer (score 3):

This should be achievable with the `list-style-type` CSS property. Try out this code below, and see if this is working how you would like:

```css
.name-list {
  list-style-type: upper-alpha;
}
```

```html
<ol class="name-list">
  <li>Bill</li>
  <li>Steve</li>
  <li>William</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I think that your answer complements the above answer well. Good job! 

As a small addition, you could apply styling only on the class directly to reduce the specificity of the given selector.

So `.a {}` instead of `ol.a {}`.

Comment: @FelixRanesberger Sure, just updated my answer to reflect this to make things simpler

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `list-style-type`.  Allowed values are listed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

```css
ul {
   list-style-type: upper-alpha
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>
```